# Definitions of semi-free DG modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, differential-graded-algebras

I saw two versions of semi-free DG modules $M$ over a small category $\mathcal{A}$, and I would like to know if they are equivalent or not.

- In many Orlov's papers, a DG $\mathcal{A}$-module $M$ is called *semi-free* if it has a filtration
  $$o=\Phi_0\subset \Phi_1\subset \cdots =P$$
  such that each quotient $\Phi_{i+1}/\Phi_i$ is free, that is, isomorphic to a direct sum of DG modules of the form $h^Y[n]$, where $Y\in \mathcal{A},\ n\in \mathbf{Z}$.
- In [Wai-Kit Yeung's paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.06352.pdf), a DG $\mathcal{A}$-module $M$ is called *semi-free* if there exists an indexed set $\{x_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in S}$ of objects $x_{\alpha}\in \mathcal{A}$, together with an isomorphism
  $$M\cong \bigoplus_{\alpha\in S}h^{x_\alpha}$$
  of underlying graded modules over the graded category after forgetting the differentials.

I like the second version more since it is more neat. However, I fail to see if these two are equivalent since we cannot guarantee that the quotient map $\Phi_{i+1}\to \Phi_{i+1}/\Phi_{i}$ splits and thus we cannot have the direct sum form of $M$ in the second definition.

Any reference or answers are welcome!

Comment: Quotient map splits exactly because the quotient is free; free modules are projective, so you can use lifting property.

Comment: @xsnl Thanks for your comment! I think here we can conclude that the morphism splits because we are working over a field $k$. We cannot use your argument because for DG module over DG caregories, free is not the “free” we usually talk about…